# &:hover not working on one specific class

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, next.js

I'm very close to completing the animation for the case study card, I was stuck on getting the client logos to appear on hover but now the styling for making the images zoom out and have lower opacity has been broken.

This is the css

```
#caseAnimationState{
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.2);
    transition: transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;

    &:hover{
      opacity: 0.7;
      transform: scale(1.02);
      transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
    }
  }

  #logoAnimationState{
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.9);
    transition: opacity 0.5s;

    &:hover{
      opacity: 1;
      transition: opacity 0.5s;
    }
  }
```

And this is the react component

```
public render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.caseStudy}>
        <h4 className="meta-label">Case Study</h4>
        <h3>{this.props.heading}</h3>
        <div className={styles.caseStudyImage}>
          <Image
            src={this.props.image}
            alt="Landscape picture"
            layout="fill"
            objectFit="cover"
            id={styles.caseAnimationState}
          />

          <Image
            src={this.props.logo}
            alt="Hover Logo"
            layout="fill"
            id={styles.logoAnimationState}
          />
        </div>
        <a href={this.props.link}>Read more</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

It is specifically this section that doesn't work

```
<Image
   src={this.props.image}
   alt="Landscape picture"
   layout="fill"
   objectFit="cover"
   id={styles.caseAnimationState}
/>
```

and the id #caseAnimationState, &:hover that is broken.

Comment: Is there any reason why you use IDs instead of classnames to apply style? This might throw a monkey wrench into your works regarding specifity.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach.

```css
#caseAnimationState{
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.2);
    transition: transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;
  }
#caseAnimationState:hover{
      opacity: 0.7;
      transform: scale(1.02);
      transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s;

  }

  #logoAnimationState{
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.9);
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
  }
#logoAnimationState:hover{
      opacity: 1;
      transition: opacity 0.5s;
  
    }
    
#myphotos {display:flex;}
```

```html
<h1>Hover on the right to see the other picture</h1>
<br />
<div id="myphotos">
<img id="caseAnimationState" width="50%" src="https://www.lovethispic.com/uploaded_images/29785-Beautiful-Red-Rose.jpg"><br>
<img id="logoAnimationState" width="50%" src="https://www.lovethispic.com/uploaded_images/29785-Beautiful-Red-Rose.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the hover

Comment: I update with sample try it again. This works for me. If it doesn't work for you let me know.